# Displaying saved localstorage variables in a textfield - javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, local-storage

i got some saved variables using localstorage, what i want to do is to put them into textfields automatically each time the page loads

```
<script language="javascript">

function save() {
    var value1 = document.getElementById("email").value;
    var value2 = document.getElementById("password").value;

    localStorage.setItem("eaddress", value1);
    localStorage.setItem("pwd", value2);

}

  </script>
```

i've got some textfields on the page namely email and password

Comment: email.value=localStorage.eaddress;

Comment: please can you put it in my code cos i'm new to javascript

Comment: possible duplicate of [Storing Objects in HTML5 localStorage](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2010892/storing-objects-in-html5-localstorage)

Comment: this's no duplicate of question, mine is to put the saved data into a textfield

Comment: What are the names of your textfields?  How are you currently populating them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to do this with jQuery, this should accomplish what you're trying to do. Please note that I couldn't get the demo running in the snippet below because Stack Overflow is preventing form submissions.

```js
$(function() {
  var
    $email = $('#email'),
    $password = $('#password'),
    emailValue = localStorage.getItem("eaddress"),
    passwordValue = localStorage.getItem("pwd");

  // SAVE VARIABLES TO LOCAL STORAGE
  $('form').on('submit', function() {
    localStorage.setItem("eaddress", $email.val());
    localStorage.setItem("pwd", $password.val());
  });
  
  // IF EMAIL AND PASSWORD ARE SAVED, PREPOPULATE THE FORM FIELDS
  if (emailValue != null) {
    $email.val(emailValue);
  }
  if (passwordValue != null) {
    $password.val(passwordValue);
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
  <input type="email" id="email" />
  <input type="password" id="password" />
  <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```